# PHPMYADMIN login form hidden

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, debian

If I go on the welcome page of phphmyadmin there's no login form.
After a double check, I notice the form is hidden:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="login_form" class="disableAjax login hide js-show" data-bitwarden-watching="1">
```

Any ideas about this?

Some tech: Server version: 10.1.45-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.12

[image: phpmyadmin login page]

Best.

Comment: Can you share your `config.inc.php`? There seems to be some issue over there

Comment: Other browsers (and possibly also testing private mode)? It may be just a" feature" of password manager, security plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I installed some upgrades in Debian (Server: 10.5.8-MariaDB-3 - Debian bullseye - PhpMyAdmin 4:5.0.4+dfsg2-1).

It's caused by wrong symbolic links to the jquery files:

- /usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js
- /usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.map

These two symbolic links are referring to files that don't exist on my computer.

My solution: replace these two symbolic links with the jquery files that you can find on https://jquery.com/download/.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime you can actually access the database and un-hide the login form by going to inspect element, and either double click on the "class" attribute, delete that whole string and then hit enter, or right click, click "edit as html", and remove the class attribute, then just click off of the text box. In either method the login form will appear and you can log in and use the database. I have had the same issue and am still trying to permanently fix. Will try the above solution with the symlinks! Also I am using firefox esr browser so you may or may not have to click on another similar option to edit the html.

Comment: Get familiar yourself with: 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask &
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I first went into my folder '/var/www/html/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/jquery'
and deleted both the jquery.min.js and jquery.min.map files.

Then I copied the code from the url 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js'
and pasted into a new file named 'jquery.min.js' inside the folder where the old one was.

Then I used 'sudo systemctl restart apache2' and when I went back to the page the login form was visible. Everything seems to be working great, and there are no more warnings and errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

All the previous answers are good, but since phpmyadmin in this case only uses links to vendor files (jquery) it would be nice to copy these files to the folder pointed to by these links. Most likely it will be `/usr/share/javascript/jquery/`. In that case, the rest of the applications can also use the same files.
In short:

- go to https://jquery.com/download/
- copy compressed production jQuery file and rename it to ' jquery.min.js '
- copy map file and rename it to ' jquery.min.map '
- copy these two files to `/usr/share/javascript/jquery/`

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues with the login form on phpMyAdmin being hidden due to the "hide" class, one solution you can try is to **use incognito mode** or **open on a different browser**.

I myself encountered a similar issue and tried this solution. In my case, the form was hidden when using Microsoft Edge, but the problem was solved by using incognito mode on Microsoft Edge. After that, the login form on phpMyAdmin was visible without any issues.

This solution is similar to the suggestion provided by [Giacomo Catenazzi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64363939/phpmyadmin-login-form-hidden#comment113819105_64363939).

I apologize if my English is not good.